# Disable submit button if two textboxes have no value not working properly

Tags: javascript, asp.net, if-statement, disabled-control

I have two text-boxes and one button. I want that the button be disabled if one of the textboxes have no value. With this code the button is enabled if just one textbox has a value.

**HTML**

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" onblur = "Toggle()"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" onblur = "Toggle()"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" Enabled = "false" />
```

**JavaScript**

```
 function Toggle() {
        var txt1 = document.getElementById("<%=TextBox1.ClientID %>");
        var txt2 = document.getElementById("<%=TextBox2.ClientID %>");
        var btn = document.getElementById("<%=Button1.ClientID %>");
        if (txt1.value == "" && txt2.value == "") {
            btn.disabled = true;
        } else {
            btn.disabled = false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Try putting a `debugger;` above that if statement and step through it.  What do you see for `value` each time?

Comment: Could you also include the compiled source? (I could debug the code without running a server)

Comment: Are you trying to disable the button if **both** textboxes are empty or if **either** is empty?

Comment: Seems to work fine.  If you have an issue try to add some details on what you want.

Comment: @ThelronCheek - Same question here. If the original question is for "either", then using `||` instead of `&&` could be the solution.

Comment: @TheIronCheek  I want to enable the button if **both** textboxes have some value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
if (txt1.value && txt2.value) btn.disabled = false;
else btn.disabled = true;
```

Comment: Yes, it's working now but I still don't understand the issue :)

Comment: `if(something)` will be true if `something` has a valid, not blank value.  That means `null`, `undefined`, and empty string will fail the check.  You want **both** textboxes to have valid value to enable... So that's what I did.

Comment: @Delboy - your issue was that your code **disabled** the button only if **both** textboxes were blank. Your code above in your question would work fine if you changed the `&&` to `||`.